# Is it possible to do TCP/IP between PCs without a router

Tags: windows, networking, network-programming

Is it possible to connect two PCs without a router using just an ethernet cable end-to-end and do socket communications over TCP/IP? I need a solution which works on windows preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to that all you need to do is if you are a using a wired connection to configure the ethernet ips to be on the same network like it has been expalianed here.
http://www.labnol.org/software/connect-computers-without-router/11049/

Answer (score 2):

Yes - there's two options:

1. If you're lucky, both PC's will support Auto-MDIX and thus auto-negotiate, in which case  you can just use a normal CAT5/CAT5e/CAT6 network cable.
2. If Auto-MDIX isn't supported then you can achieve the same at a physical level with an [ethernet crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). This is a standard CAT5/CAT5e/CAT6 network cable but has the tx and rx pairs "crossed over" so that they are connected to the right terminals at each end.

Regardless of which one works for you, you'll need to configure a static IP on the interfaces, both on the same subnet (e.g., for a netmask of 255.255.255.0 then for an IP address that matches 192.168.x.y, x should be the same for both hosts, but each host has a different y).

Comment: one upvote for pointing out Auto-MDIX

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! You must...

1. statically configure the IP address of each computer (192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2, for example).
2. Configure each computer to be in the same subnet (both 255.255.255.0, for example).
3. Buy a *Cross Over* ethernet cable or use a hub or a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that kind of connection using a [cross-over cable](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkcables/g/bldef_crossover.htm).